# How to make a table bigger in LaTeX

Tags: tables, alignment

How can I expand the size of a table to surpass the layout of the overall text?

I mean, originally, it looks like this:

> [image]

And I want to make the table like this:

> [image]

Here is my code in LaTeX (in case you need it):

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\tiny  \begin{tabular{||p{0.7cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|} 
    \hline
    & PM & PB & MT\_RACHAT & TAUX & AGE & ANCIEN & RACHTOT & RACHPART & TAUXRACH\\ [0.8ex] 
    \hline\hline
    Min & 0 & 0 &0 &0 & 0,1006 & 0& 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    \hline
    Median & 7 685 & 143.68 & 0 & 0 &64.3333&12.72&0&0&0 \\
    \hline
    Mean &  32 231  &886.31 &1541&  0.3449& 60.5677&    12.64&  809.7&  854.2&  1 541 \\
    \hline
    Max &3 528 826  &204 718.24&    1 358 526&  2.0000& 107.2355&   34.30&  925888.8&   1358526.1&  1 358 526 \\
    [1ex] 
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\caption{tbale}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\hspace*{-2cm}\begin{tabular}.....\end{tabular}\hspace*{-2cm}` and increase the widt of the p columns

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is a possible solution via `adjustbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \tiny
    \begin{adjustbox}{tabular=lll,center}
      \begin{tabular}{||p{0.7cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|} 
    \hline
    & PM & PB & MT\_RACHAT & TAUX & AGE & ANCIEN & RACHTOT & RACHPART & TAUXRACH\\[0.8ex] 
    \hline\hline
    Min & 0 & 0 &0 &0 & 0,1006 & 0& 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    \hline
    Median & 7 685 & 143.68 & 0 & 0 &64.3333&12.72&0&0&0 \\
    \hline
    Mean &  32 231  &886.31 &1541&  0.3449& 60.5677&    12.64&  809.7&  854.2&  1 541 \\
    \hline
    Max &3 528 826  &204 718.24&    1 358 526&  2.0000& 107.2355&   34.30&  925888.8&   1358526.1&  1 358 526 \\[1ex] 
    \hline
      \end{tabular}
  \end{adjustbox}
\end{center}
\caption{table}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to put the tabular in a centered box without horizontal space, but consider format the table in other way, to fit the  margins and improve also in some other aspects:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,parskip}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[6][1-8]
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering\makebox[0pt]{\tiny%
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.7cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{1.5cm}|cccc} 
    \hline
    & PM & PB & MT\_RACHAT & TAUX & AGE & ANCIEN & RACHTOT & RACHPART & TAUXRACH\\ [0.8ex] 
    \hline\hline
    Min & 0 & 0 &0 &0 & 0,1006 & 0& 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
    \hline
    Median & 7 685 & 143.68 & 0 & 0 &64.3333&12.72&0&0&0 \\
    \hline
    Mean &  32 231  &886.31 &1541&  0.3449& 60.5677&    12.64&  809.7&  854.2&  1 541 \\
    \hline
    Max &3 528 826  &204 718.24&    1 358 526&  2.0000& 107.2355&   34.30&  925888.8&   1358526.1&  1 358 526 \\
    [1ex] 
    \hline
\end{tabular}}
\caption{wider table centered} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]\tabcolsep2.4pt
\small% 
\begin{tabular}{@{}l
S[table-format=7.0]
S[table-format=7.2]
S[table-format=7.0]
S[table-format=1.4]
S[table-format=3.4]
S[table-format=2.2]
S[table-format=5.1]
S[table-format=7.1]
S[table-format=7.0]
@{}}\toprule 
       & {\scriptsize  PM}  & {\scriptsize  PB} & {\scriptsize  MT\_RACHAT} & {\scriptsize  TAUX} & {\scriptsize  AGE} & {\scriptsize  ANCIEN} & {\scriptsize  RACHTOT} & {\scriptsize  RACHPART} & {\scriptsize  TAUXRACH}\\
\cmidrule(rl){2-2}
\cmidrule(rl){3-3}
\cmidrule(rl){4-4}
\cmidrule(rl){5-5}
\cmidrule(rl){6-6}
\cmidrule(rl){7-7}
\cmidrule(rl){8-8}
\cmidrule(rl){9-9}
\cmidrule(rl){10-10}
Min    & 0  & 0 &0 &0 & 0.1006 & 0& 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
Median & 7 685 & 143.68 & 0 & 0 &64.3333 &12.72&0&0&0 \\
Mean   &  32231  &886.31 &1541&  0.3449& 60.5677&    12.64&  809.7&  854.2&  1541 \\
Max    & 3528826  &204718.24&    1358526&  2.0000& 107.2355&   34.30&  925888.8&   1358526.1&  1358526 \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{better table, not centered, not exceding margins}
\end{table}

\lipsum[6][1-8]
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I always recommend that users create a `displaytbl` environment for surrounding their `tabular`s. A typical definition is:

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{displaytbl}{}
   {\begin{center}}
   {\end{center}}
```

Now if we want to extend to the margins, this doesn't work, but we can make a small modification that will allow it in `displaytbl` only with the following:

```
\makeatletter % ❶
\NewDocumentEnvironment{displaytbl}{}
   {
    \@flushglue = 0pt plus1fil minus1in % ❷
    \begin{center}
   }
   {\end{center}}
\makeatother
```

We need access to a private variable of LaTeX, so we will use `\makeatletter` ❶ before we define `displaytbl` then `\makeatother` afterwards. The private variable we're going to change is `\@flushglue` ❷ which, by default is `0pt plus1fil`. By adding a `minus` term to it, we allow things to stick into the margin. I set it to `1in` but you probably want a smaller value, depending on your margins. Plain TeX does centering using a value of `0pt plus1fil minus1fil` which allows unlimited extension into the margins, but that could lead to silently pushing things further into the margins than you really want. Setting a hard limit gives better control.

Note also that the setting must be done *before* we call `\begin{center}` since otherwise the value won't be used when `\begin{center}` sets its left and right margins.